# Login Mvc con sql sin entity

Tags: html, c#, sql, sql-server, mvc

Tengo una cuestión, necesito hacer un login que me mande a una página específica según el nivel de usuario. Es decir, a modo de ejemplo:

```
**Usuario nivel 1 -> pagina1
Usuario nivel 2 -> pagina2**
```

Pero, no me estaría resultando ya que me sale que no se encuentra la vista Login. Por lo que necesito saber si estoy haciéndolo bien.

**Clase:**

```
public class Usuarios
    {
        public string usuario { get; set; }
        public string clave { get; set; }
        public decimal? nivel { get; set; }

        public Usuarios(string usuario, string clave, decimal? nivel) 
        {
            this.usuario = usuario;
            this.clave = clave;
            this.nivel = nivel;
        }
    }
```

**Clase ConexionSQL:**

```
public List<Usuarios> login(string usu, string cla)
        {
            List<Usuarios> salida = new List<Usuarios>();
            string con = "cadena";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT Count(*), nivel " +
                    "FROM usuarios " +
                    "WHERE usuario = @usu " +
                    "AND clave = @cla " +
                    "AND AccesoSistemaProvidus = 1";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usu", usu);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cla", cla);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string usuario = dr["usuario"]?.ToString();
                    string clave = dr["clave"]?.ToString();
                    decimal? nivel = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["nivel"]?.ToString());
                    Usuarios u = new Usuarios(usuario, clave, nivel);
                    salida.Add(u);
                }
                connection.Close();
                return salida;
            }
        }
```

**Controlador:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


public ActionResult Login(string usu, string cla)
    {
        try
        {
            ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
            var caracteres = Convert.ToString(cla);
            var usuario = sql.login(usu, cla);

            if (usuario.Count <= 0)
            {
                ViewBag.MensajeUsuario = "El usuario es inexistente.";
            }
            else if (usuario[0].nivel == 0
                || usuario[0].nivel == 1
                || usuario[0].nivel == 2
                || usuario[0].nivel == 7)
            {
                return View("Login1");
            }
            else if (usuario[0].nivel == 3
                || usuario[0].nivel == 4
                || usuario[0].nivel == 16)
            {
                return View("Login2");
            }
            else 
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return View("");
    }
```

**Index:**

```
<form class="modal-content animate" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                <img src="~/Images/00.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <label for="uname"><b>Usuario:</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese usuario..." name="uname" required>

                <label for="psw"><b>Contraseña:</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." name="psw" required>

                <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Recuérdame
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Login1:**

```
<p>Nivel 1</p>
```

**Login2:**

```
<p>Nivel 2</p>
```

¿Qué es lo que está mal? Porque me sale este error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: La consulta con parámetros '(@usu nvarchar(4000),@cla nvarchar(4000))SELECT Count(*), nivel ' espera el parámetro '@usu', que no se ha proporcionado.
```

¿Sugerencias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los nombres de los parámetros de la acción en un controlador deben coincidir con el nombre de los parámetros que se están enviando en la petición http.

Si la acción `Login()` espera los parámetros : `usu` y `cla` entonces en el formulario deben llamarse de igual forma. En este caso, en el formulario, el nombre de usuario es: `uname` y la contraseña es: `psw`. Por esa razón en la acción no se les asigna un valor.

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta super compacta: Porque es nulo

Motivo del por qué es nulo:

En tu controlador, pides `usu` y `cla`:

```
public ActionResult Login(string usu, string cla)
```

En tu vista, estás definiendo a `usu` como `uname` y a `cla` como `psw`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese usuario..." name="uname" required>
<input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." name="psw" required>
```

Solución:

1. Corregir el nombre.
2. Acomodar la ruta adecuadamente.

En la configuración de tus rutas:

```
routes.MapRoute(    
"nombreDeLaRuta",    
"Login/{usu}/{cla}",    
new { controller = "Login", action = " Login", usu= UrlParameter.Optional, cla = UrlParameter.Optional }    
);
```

Dato importante: Cuida las claves, normalmente van en un POST y no mostrándose en una URL.